Модификатор в opencart почему не меняет значения файлах папки system/storage/modification 2.3?
есть модификатор, для 2.3 установка проходит, но суть в том что модифицировать пробуем файл в system/storage/modification и соответственно данные не меняются, ну все уже проверили, вот код модификатора
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
<name>Sat verification modifier yandex_payments</name>
<code>Sa_verification_modifier_yandex_payments</code>
<version>1.1</version>
<author>sat_siziyyy</author>

<file path="system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/checkout/success.php|system/storage/modification/system/engine/loader.php">  <!-- Файл который будет модифицироваться -->
    <operation>
        <search>                           <!-- Поиск кода в файле -->
            <![CDATA[
            $data['script_order'] = $this->{'model_'.str_replace("/", "_", $prefix).'payment_yandex_money'}->getMetricsJavaScript($this->session->data['order_id']);
            ]]>
        </search>
        <add position="replace">             <!-- Добавление модификации (после найденного куска кода) -->
            <![CDATA[
            if ($this->{'model_'.str_replace("/", "_", $prefix).'payment_yandex_money'} && method_exists($this->{'model_'.str_replace("/", "_", $prefix).'payment_yandex_money'}, 'getMetricsJavaScript')) {
            $data['script_order'] =  $this->{'model_'.str_replace("/", "_", $prefix).'payment_yandex_money'}->getMetricsJavaScript($this->session->data['order_id']);
            } else {
            $data['script_order'] = '';
            }
            ]]>
        </add>
    </operation>

    <operation>
        <search>                           <!-- Поиск кода в файле -->
            <![CDATA[
            throw new \Exception('Error: Could not load model ' . $route . '!');
            ]]>
        </search>
        <add position="replace">             <!-- Добавление модификации (после найденного куска кода) -->
            <![CDATA[
            if($route == 'extension/payment/yandex_money') {
                return true;
            } else {
                try {
                    throw new \Exception('Error:  Could not load model ' . $route . '!');
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    // Ничего не делаем, просто проигнорируем ошибку
                }
            }
            ]]>
        </add>
    </operation>
</file>

